# VSCode Debugging Protractor with Typescript/ts-node and skipping node_internals

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, protractor, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug protractor tests that make use of ts-node. I successfully get breakpoints hit using the below `launch.json` configuration. The problem is that it seems that `skipFiles` is not working as I want it to based on vscode's documentation for [skipping uninteresting code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code).

It seems that this is successfully skipping anything in `node_modules` folder, but I'm still hitting node_internals files, specifically, it always stops on the file `<node_internals>\internal\per_context\primordial.js`

Launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Protractor (ts-node)",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/protractor.conf.js",
                "--require", "ts-node/register"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**",
                "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

my ts.config:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Other environment info**

- OS: Windows 10
- protractor@7.0.0
- typescript@4.1.2
- tsnode@9.0.0

Comment: Hi, So is there any update on this question ?, If so kindly add them.

Comment: @SARANSURYA - unfortunately not. I'm still just dealing with this issue by setting breakpoints everywhere I want it to stop and using "Continue" instead of "Step Over" : (

Comment: Thanks @TylerNielsen for the update. Hoping it gets resolved soon.